# jQuery function is not working expectedly

Tags: jquery

below **JQuery** code for showing and hiding content of my html page. when i click on  **show product** link all names of product comes below and when click **hide product** link it hides products. it is working as expected but in **IE6.0** when i click on **hide product** link it is hiding check box also but in  **mozilla** it is as expected

```
$(document.ready(function()){
    toggleNodes=function(node,action){
        var $content=$('.node-content', node);
        var $symbol=$('.node-label>a>.ui-symbol-green',node);

        If  ( var ($symbol.hasClass('ui-symbol-circle-minus') && 
              (action==undefined||action=='hide')))
        {
            $symbol.removeClass('ui-symbol-circle-minus');
            $symbol.addClass('ui-symbol-circle-plus');
            $info.addClass('closed');
            $content.hide();
        }
        else if($symbol.hasClass('ui-symbol-circle-plus')) && 
                (action=='undefined'||action=='undefined')
            $symbol.addClass('ui-symbol-circle-minus');

        $symbol.removeClass('ui-symbol-circle-plus');
        $info.removeClass('closed');
        $content.show();
      }
      return false;
    }

    toggleAllNodes=function(tree,action){
        $('.node',tree).each(function(node)){
            toggleNOde(node,action);
        });
    }

    $('.tree .nodelabel>a').click(function(event)){
        toggleNode(event.currentTarget.parentNode.parentNode);
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
return false;
```

Please suggest how to correct this bug.

Comment: Could you post a snippet of your html (it can be filled with dummy text). Also, can you fix the formatting of the code you have now to make it easier to read.

Comment: Try to use jQuery's toggle method and it's callback function to handle the icon swith. It 'll make your code a lot more readable and probably fix your bug.

Comment: If that is an exact paste of your code there are a few syntax errors

Comment: Just a sidenote, most serious webdevelopers have seized to supporting IE6, because the browser is simply too old to make everything work. I'd suggest you move on too (unless you have a specific reason for developing for IE6).

Comment: In your code snippet, the `{` for the else-if seems to be missing. Is this also the case with your actual code, or is it just a copy-n-paste error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to put `var` before the function defining.. IE has problems with it!

```
$(document.ready(function()){
    var toggleNodes=function(node,action) {
        var $content=$('.node-content', node);
        var $symbol=$('.node-label>a>.ui-symbol-green',node);

        // also think that this IF statement is not going to work for IE (!not sure)
        if( var ($symbol.hasClass('ui-symbol-circle-minus') && (action==undefined||action=='hide'))) {
            $symbol.removeClass('ui-symbol-circle-minus');
            $symbol.addClass('ui-symbol-circle-plus');
            $info.addClass('closed');
            $content.hide();
        }
        else if($symbol.hasClass('ui-symbol-circle-plus')) && (action=='undefined'||action=='undefined')
            $symbol.addClass('ui-symbol-circle-minus');

        $symbol.removeClass('ui-symbol-circle-plus');
        $info.removeClass('closed');
        $content.show();}
        return false;
    }

    var toggleAllNodes=function(tree,action){
        $('.node',tree).each(function(node)){
            toggleNOde(node,action);
        });
    }

    $('.tree .nodelabel>a').click(function(event)){
        toggleNode(event.currentTarget.parentNode.parentNode);
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Your welcome! there are some basic stuff to short you code that works in modern browsers, but not in IE #fail